# vSphere client 5.1- it downloads 5.0 support files

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I am trying to install vSphere Client 5.1 on Windows 8.
When I download and install, and then open the application, it says that it needs to download support files from the internet.

Once it does that, I open the support files, with filename `VMware-viclient-all-5.0.0-455964-5.0.exe` (notice it is version 5.0, not 5.1).

Why does it do that? When I try to install these (although they are the wrong version, I thought I would see if it would work anyway), it says that it is only compatabile with version of Windows XP SP2 and above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you downloading it from the ESXi server?

Comment: The client will maintain libraries for backwards compatibility with servers.  If you connect to a version 5.0 server you will be prompted to download the appropriate libraries.

Comment: OK makes sense... so I think my answer is this... I am trying to use 5.1 client on a 5.0 hypervisor?

Answer (score -1):

As Keith pointed out in the comments, when you try to connect to a vcenter or host of a different version, the viclient will download the applicable support libraries, and use them libraries to connect.

You can see which version of the viclient you are actually using by clicking help -> About Vmware Vsphere, and look at the vsphere client version number. When you connect to different versions of hosts and vcenters, you will see this version number change. You will also be prompted to download the correct libraries if you don't have them already

Comment: What do you mean by C# client? I don't think you are correct, as I have downloaded the 5.1 client.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm completely wrong here! Keith's answer is correct (see his comment)